# Use the plane wave expansion to explain the fundamental limit of resolution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, plane-wave

As stated in the title I don't really understand how I can explain the fundamental limit of resolution using plane wave expansion. The question was asked by my professor and seems a bit vague to me. My thought was that since we are Fourier transforming all information in the Fourier transform of features in our object smaller than $\lambda$/2 is lost as the wave propagates.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by resolution here? Do you mean resolving a physical structure by some form of measurement using a wave or wave-like method? I.e. imaging or diffraction? Or do you mean measuring energy level spacing? Or something else?

Comment: Resolving a physical structure using a wave.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Signal_processing

Comment: Thank you! I found some paper on the internet written by my professor where he explains the classical resolution limit with the uncertainty principle and it was a very easy and straightforward explanation, however, what bothers me is that it is said in the question to use the plane wave expansion which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I would interpret "plane wave expansion" here to be a synonym for "Fourier transform."